# Catch ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE in IFrame in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, x-frame-options

I have a javascript application developed with Ext.NET. I am loading pages in an IFrame.
When user session expires, the IFrame tries to load the login screen from another domain and it can't, of course. 
I would like to catch this in javascript and redirect the whole page.

Is there a way to do this?

"Refused to display *Domain Address* in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."